# Message not picked up by component from receiver (threading issue?)

Tags: multithreading, mule

We experience spurious errors when picking up a message from a JMS queue (Websphere MQ) for further processing with Mule (v. 2.2.1). Below I have included the affected service as well as extracts from the Mule log. The first segment, with "DispatchThread: 1", is the case when the service worked as expected and the second case, with "DispatchThread: 6", the message is lost i.e. not processed.

As indicated by the log the message is queued up as an event for the processFooBar.service to process in both cases but in the latter case it’s never picked up for further processing. In the working example it’s almost immediately de-queued and processed.

We suspect that this is caused by an imbalance in the threading profiles, i.e. the receiver-threading-profile etc, but at the same time we feel that it’s a pretty vague explanation. It’s a bit worrying that a message can get lost without a trace and even if we increase the number of threads we might experience the same issue if there is an increased load on the system.

I would appreciate if our suspicions can be confirmed and if somebody experienced the same issue, what they did about it? We will upgrade to Mule 3 but I suspect that this issue is no different for Mule 3?

Service definition:

```
<service name="processFooBar">
    <inbound>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="A.FROM.BAR"
                              connector-ref="fooConnector"
                              disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true">
            <transformers>
                <transformer ref="messageLogger"/>
                <transformer ref="jmsMessageToObjectTransformer"/>
                ...
                ..
            </transformers>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </inbound>
    ...
    ..
</service>
```

Log extracts:

```
...
..
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,319 DEBUG [DispatchThread: 1] org.mule.service.AbstractService - Service: processFooBar has received asynchronous event on: jms://A.FROM.BAR
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,319 DEBUG [DispatchThread: 1] org.mule.model.seda.SedaService - Service: processFooBar has received asynchronous event on: jms://A.FROM.BAR
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,319 DEBUG [DispatchThread: 1] org.mule.model.seda.SedaService - Service processFooBar putting event on queue processFooBar.service: MuleEvent: ..., endpointEncoding=UTF-8}
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,321 DEBUG [processFooBar.1] org.mule.model.seda.SedaService - Service: processFooBar dequeued event on: jms://A.FROM.BAR
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,331 DEBUG [processFooBar.1] org.mule.model.seda.SedaService - Service processFooBar polling queue processFooBar.service, timeout = 10,000
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,339 DEBUG [processFooBar.2] org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage - new copy of message for Thread[processFooBar.2,5,main]
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,367 DEBUG [processFooBar.2] org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer - Setting transformer name to: fooDecoderTransformer
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,368 DEBUG [processFooBar.2] org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer - java.lang.Object has been added as source type for this transformer, there will be no source type checking performed
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 10:31:37,368 DEBUG [processFooBar.2] org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer - Setting transformer name to: objectToStringTransformer
...
..
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 13:19:51,896 DEBUG [DispatchThread: 6] org.mule.service.AbstractService - Service: processFooBar has received asynchronous event on: jms://FOMS.FROM.FSM.Bar
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 13:19:51,896 DEBUG [DispatchThread: 6] org.mule.model.seda.SedaService - Service: processFooBar has received asynchronous event on: jms://FOMS.FROM.FSM.Bar
@ESB-: 2013-06-24 13:19:51,897 DEBUG [DispatchThread: 6] org.mule.model.seda.SedaService - Service processFooBar putting event on queue processFooBar.service: MuleEvent: ..., endpointEncoding=UTF-8}
...
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Mule has a limit to max thread default to 16, so you can go ahead and change:

First thing you can

1. Set the numberOfConsumers attribute on the JMS connector
2. Set the maxThreadsActive attribute on the JMS connector’s receiver-threading-profile element

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector" numberOfConsumers="15" brokerURL="vm://localhost">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="15"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

Another solution is you can set flow processing strategy, please refer to the below link: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/flow-processing-strategies